# Compose and send HTML emails with Google Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to compose and sent HTML email with Google Gmail? Is there a maybe Chrome Extension which enables that? Or is there web client which can do that?

UPDATE: Yes, Gmail does support sending emails in HTML format, but I would like to edit a little more (in similar as http://www.tumblr.com/ has a way to edit your blog post)

Comment: Wouldn't Gmail already send in HTML format, being primarily a browser based email system? If you've found this to be false, what format is it using by default?

Comment: The problem is that I want to send simple tables, modify size of embedded photo and add borders to a text.

Comment: You understand that they limit your formatting because not everyone has a email client able to read more richly formated messages right?  Have you considred using your favorite desktop-client and composing and sending the message via SMTP?

Comment: There is a little doubt that editing HTML should be possible. Some people used to do some hacking in the old days that Gmail didn't support HTML at all. http://www.dslreports.com/faq/12016

Comment: I was just looking around with the same question in mind, and I came across a very likely-looking post from Amit Agarwal: "[Send HTML Emails with Gmail and Google Docs](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-html-email/19672/)." Haven't actually tried it out yet, but since I had this page opened in another tab from the searching, I figured I'd post the link before I forgot.

Comment: Can you at least summarize what one will find at that link? Answers that don't contain anything useful beyond a link out to a different site aren't really answers.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-html-email/19672/) works great. Someone wrote a script in a [Google Doc](https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmxApiq9b5Q9dGpyNy1jMjhrUk0tUkVFcmpJYlF2d2c&newcopy=true) which can send an email in HTML. Just copy/paste the HTML in the script's dialog box and set the `to`, `cc`, and `bcc` and it'll send it using your google account with which you are currently logged in.

Comment: Be aware that the script `sendEmail` is not authorize by Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

From a client, it's no problem...from the Gmail website, I only know of people having luck with copy/paste of HTML and typically having to embed it inside a signature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any extensions that would do that for you however if you really need to send an HTML email, design your email in any HTML editor (eg. NetBeans, dreamweaver...), "run" your page in a web browser, copy and paste the content of the webpage to gmail and send it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins/extensions that allow you to compose and send HTML emails directly from Gmail. BeeFree's Gmail add-on is one such tool.

However, since you require more flexibility I would suggest you to design your email using [BeeFree.io's online editor](https://beefree.io/editor) and then send the email using `Google AppScripts`.

Even though the whole process looks more complicated, it's fairly simple. I suggest you check out my article on [sending HTML emails with AppScripts](https://codegena.com/send-mail-merge-html-emails-using-google-appscripts/) here.